# How to stop Mouseleave from triggering on elements that appear over target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, mouseleave

jQuery's mouseleave seems to trigger on any covering elements. I don't want these covering elements to be considered as "outside" my target area. Here's a simple example using the datepicker from jQueryUI:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Wm9L/

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({});

$(".wrapper")
.mouseenter(function(){
    $("#status").html("Status: Mouse is INSIDE");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $("#status").html("Status: Mouse is OUTSIDE");
});
```

Notice that the mouseleave is triggered when the mouse is over the datepicker. What's a good solution to prevent this for this datepicker example? And what's a good solution for any future elements I might add that cover the target?

Comment: The issue here is that the datepicker popup is absolutely positioned, and as such is not a child of the `.wrapper` element. Therefore any mouse activity on it will not be bubbled up to `.wrapper`. A workaround would be to check the mouse co-ordinates against the known boundaries of the `.wrapper` element, although this will be ugly. Someone else may know of a better solution.

Comment: The datepicker is appended outside your wrapper.That is the reason.

Comment: This is an alternative to the co-ords method I mentioned, but will be *very* easily broken in jQUI changes its' class names: http://jsfiddle.net/6Wm9L/2/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6Wm9L/4/ : A workaround for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `relatedTarget` event's property to filter your handler:

```
.mouseleave(function(e){
    if($(e.relatedTarget).closest('.ui-datepicker').length) return;
    $("#status").html("Status: Mouse is OUTSIDE");
});
```

### --DEMO--

Comment: very nice, I was attempting to find something with `isTarget`, but this seems to do the trick!

Comment: Very nice solution. This would be a worthwhile addition to jQuery core events. I've not used the `relatedTarget` property before time to do some reading on MDN :)

Comment: Ah, since the relatedTarget is the other element involved in the event then I can just include a list of classes here that relate to covering elements that I don't want to be considered as "outside". Love it!